# How to find vmware's locahost server from host

Tags: vmware

I have a website server running on my VMware on the same pc. I want to know how I can get the IP of that server through my host. My server is running red hat, it's "saved state". SO its not a physical OS where I can go in and browse my red hat. Is there away I can ping that server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in one of two ways. Do you have root access to the machine either from the console? If so log in and use /sbin/ifconfig to find the address.
If not look for the file dhcpd.leases (On Linux it is in /etc/vmware/vmnet8/dhcpd for NAT /etc/vmware/vmnet1/dhcpd for host -only. In the file there are a number of blocks of data :-

```
lease ip-address {
hardware ethernet MAC address
}
```

Match the ip address to the MAC address and you have it.

e.g.
MAC Address 00:0C:29:64:B4:EF

```
lease 192.168.240.138 {
    starts 4 2013/03/07 17:19:44;
    ends 4 2013/03/07 17:49:44;
    hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:64:b4:ef;
}
```

Note the Mac address match, the ip address is 192.168.240.138

/sbin/ifconfig on the virtual machine gives

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:64:b4:ef  
          inet addr:192.168.240.138  Bcast:192.168.240.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Hope this helps.
I suspect there will be a similar file in VMWare on Windows, but I would have to check

Comment: On Windows 7 the file can be found in C:\ProgramData\vmware